# Google Analytics Goals: Prevent tracking of URL parameters of subfolders

Tags: google-analytics, subdirectory

On my site I am tracking the URL `/shop/` as goal by **head match**. As there are some URL parameters I cannot use exact match here.

Additionally, I am tracking a goal by **exact match** which is a URL to subfolder: `/shop/process/paid.php`

The problem is that GA tracks this subfolder with the head match as well, and thus saves the URL parameters that come along with paid.php, e.g. *paid.php?email=customer@home.com*

How can I prevent GA to track the URL parameters? 
How would the setup look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work with a custom filter:

admin->profile->filters->custom filter->search and replace.

Search for

```
/shop/process/paid.php\?.*
```

(that's your url with arbitrary query parameters, the "\" is an escape sign since "?" is also an control character in regular expression. Dot means any character and "*" means any number of the preceding (in that case any) character) and replace with the desired url ( /shop/process/paid.php).

There is probably a more elegant solution but like most people I'm not good at this regex stuff. This should work however.

Alternatives:

- If those query parameters are nowhere needed in the tracking data you can exlude them completely in the profile settings.
- You can created a profile for the subdirectory based on the directory (include filter->request uri contains "/shop" and set only this profile to remove query parameters

Comment: Thanks Eike, I set up the filter (with Filter Field: Request URI), and report back in 2-3 days if it worked.